# How to rewrite url in multi language asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes

I want to differentiate the url of my website when implementing multi-language website, I want the url to be like this:

English version :
http://www.mysite.com/en/default.aspx

French version :
http://www.mysite.com/fr/default.aspx

what I want to do is the same page but adding the language code to the url.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO... Please take a minute to read how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It would be helpful to see what you've tried and to know any limitations you have, what server platform (IIS6 or IIS7 for example).

Comment: thanks for your comment, I am using iis7 and vs2008

Comment: do you mean > same page ,but different parameter and different url ?

Comment: yes the same url but with the language code for every language